# How to check mysql status on FreeBSD?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, freebsd

First, I will write that why I want to do it.

When I run a Ruby on Rails' database rake comamnd, it showed:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I created that file:

```
touch /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and run the command again. I showed:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)
```

I have search it by Google, most of them said that should check mysql's status.

I am using FreeBSD 9.1 now. From this article there is a good method to do that:

> http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-start-stop-restart-mysql-server/

But unlucky, I can't find `mysql-server` in my `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/` directory.

I want to know where my mysql is, so I run:

```
whereis mysql
```

It showed me this only:

```
mysql: /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

But when I try:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql status
```

It showed:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)
```

In other way, if I try to connect my mysql using this command:

```
mysql -utom -p1234 -h my_mysql_host_name
```

I can connect my local database.

I don't know the reason about `/tmp/mysql.sock`. It seems a bad issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status:

```
# service mysql-server status
mysql is running as pid 45699.
# ps 45699
  PID  TT  STAT    TIME COMMAND
45699  ??  I    0:00.50 [mysqld]
```

Did you follow the MySQL installation instructions & ensure GNUMake was installed on the system prior to installing mysql?  It sounds like your installation is only half there ... if at all.

You should have a startup script in /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server -- it's absence is a clue that the install isn't correct.

Lastly, you can't just "create" a socket in /tmp (.."touch /tmp...) and expect it to work.  It's not there for a reason... Likely because your install isn't complete.

Once you have things installed right, you should be able to get the status by typing

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/freebsd-installation.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer very much. You are right, when I type `service mysql-server status`, it showed: `mysql-server does not exist in /etc/rc.d or the local startup directories (/usr/local/etc/rc.d)`. Now I am using a rental server with no root permission, I am using it's service. I don't know how it installed mysql but can connect by `mysql` command. And, I can't find `ports` directory under `/usr`. Maybe I should ask supplier.

Answer (score 1):

Type  `service mysql-server status` 
If you appears that mysql is not running. 
Check file `etc/rc.conf`  check your line `mysql_enable="YES"` If you have added manually.

After the `service mysql-server start`

If not working even now, do the following steps:
-Type `service mysql-server stop`
-go on `var/db` and delete mysql folder
-go on `/tmp` and delete mysql.sock
-type in console `service mysql-server start`
-Now check if mysql is running process.`service mysql-server status`

If it works now create an user :

```
mysql -u root
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@"%"
IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

BIG EDIT :
If you have not installed mysql:
Upgrade the ports: `portsnap fetch extract`
Move on mysq dir: `cd /usr/ports/databases/mysql56-server`
Make install: `make install clean`

Another EDIT :
If you want to decrease the time, you can use `pkg`. which takes about 5 minutes to install mysql with him.

With pkg : `pkg install mysql56-server` and it's done select `Y` to confirm install and wait . Now configure `rc.conf` and set mysql user , done